# Validating registration for using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am new to JavaScript, I am currently working on validating a registration form with JavaScript. I don't seem to get the knack of it. 
Here is the codepen link to the form:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/timothy-ogundipe/pen/KKwwoKL)

Please point out what I am doing wrong.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#submit");
let message = document.querySelector("#id");
let form = document.forms["login"]
let field1 = document.forms["login"]["firstName"];
let field2 = document.forms["login"]["lasttName"];
let field3 = document.forms["login"]["emailAddress"];
let field4 = document.forms["login"]["password"];



button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  function submit() {
    if (field1.value == "") {
      message.textContext = "Fill in your first name";
      return false;
    }
    if (field2.value == "") {
      message.textContext = "Fill in your last name";
      return false;
    }
    if (field3.value == "") {
      message.textContext = "Fill in your email address";
      return false;
    }
    if (field4.value == "") {
      message.textContext = "Type in your desired password";
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  width: 70%;
}

.input-text {
  width: 97%;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #56b4ff;
  color: white;
}

.inline {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#box2 {
  margin-left: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register Here</h1>
    <p id="id"></p>
    <form class="login" name="login" onsubmit="return submit()">
      <div class="inline">
        <div class="input" id="box1">
          <p>First Name</p>
          <input class="input-text" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input" id="box2">
          <p>Last Name</p>
          <input class="input-text" type="text" name="lasttName" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input" id="box3">
        <p>E-mail address</p>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="E-mail address">
      </div>
      <div class="input" id="box4">
        <p>Password</p>
        <input class="input-text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="submit" id="submit">Register</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I clicked `edit` then `[<>]` snippet editor and created a [mcve] for you HERE instead of externally which can suffer from link rot

Comment: Please see the update to my answer. I have streamlined some of the code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues

- Use the submit event of the form
- Do not have an inner named function
- use preventDefault passing the event to the function
- NEVER call anything ="submit"
- I prefer getElementById if the element has an ID
- form name is obsolete
- do not use "id" as `id`  - it is confusing

I streamlined the code a little

```js
let message = document.getElementById("message");
let form = document.getElementById("login");
let field1 = form.firstName;
let field2 = form.lasttName;
let field3 = form.emailAddress;
let field4 = form.password;
let messages = [];


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  if (field1.value == "") {
    messages.push("Fill in your first name");
  }
  if (field2.value == "") {
    messages.push("Fill in your last name");
  }
  if (field3.value == "") {
    messages.push("Fill in your email address");
  }
  if (field4.value == "") {
    messages.push("Type in your desired password");
  }
  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    message.innerText = messages.join("\n");
  }
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  width: 70%;
}

.input-text {
  width: 97%;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #56b4ff;
  color: white;
}

.inline {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#box2 {
  margin-left: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register Here</h1>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <form class="login" id="login">
      <div class="inline">
        <div class="input" id="box1">
          <p>First Name</p>
          <input class="input-text" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input" id="box2">
          <p>Last Name</p>
          <input class="input-text" type="text" name="lasttName" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input" id="box3">
        <p>E-mail address</p>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="E-mail address">
      </div>
      <div class="input" id="box4">
        <p>Password</p>
        <input class="input-text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="submit">Register</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. it will works fine.

```
let button = document.querySelector("#submit");
let message = document.querySelector("#id") ;
let form = document.forms["login"]
let field1 = document.forms["login"]["firstName"];
let field2 = document.forms["login"]["lasttName"];
let field3 = document.forms["login"]["emailAddress"];
let field4 = document.forms["login"]["password"];



  button.addEventListener("click", () =>{

      if (field1.value == "") {
        message.innerHTML = "Fill in your first name";
        console.log(message.textContext,message)
        return false;
      }
      if (field2.value == "") {
        message.innerHTML = "Fill in your last name";
        return false;
      }
      if (field3.value == "") {
        message.innerHTML = "Fill in your email address";
        return false;
      }
      if (field4.value == "") {
        message.innerHTML = "Type in your desired password";
        return false;
      }

  })
```